# Getting the checked value of a mat-checkbox - Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm trying to get the value (true or false) of a checked input control

```js
it('Is checkbox checked', () => {
  cy.get('mat-checkbox[formcontrolname=favorite]').should('be.checked')
})
```

But the assertion always fails

Answer (score 1):

You must access the native input

```
it('Is checkbox checked', () => {
  cy
    .get('mat-checkbox[formcontrolname=favorite]')
    .get('[type="checkbox"]')
    .check()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to find the native input

```js
it('Is checkbox checked', () => {
  cy.get('mat-checkbox[formcontrolname=favorite] input').should('be.checked')
})
```